# how quick is terraform updated if a new gcp feature is released?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

if the google cloud platform(GCP) is releasing a new feature, generally in how much time terraform update, to support that new GCP feature? Please let me know, it will be very helpful.

Comment: This depends on the development teams and priorities set for each feature. This means there is no fact based answer only opinions. I would review the Terraform release notes and compare to Google Cloud release notes and compare the dates of when a GCP feature was released and the corresponding release in Terraform. That will give you an indication. In some cases you will find that Terraform has the feature before GA from Google as the teams do work closely together. In other cases you will find delays for some features.

Comment: The Google Cloud Terraform Provider is developed by Google and is released by Google.  Terraform itself is released by HashiCorp. This means two different teams are involved in the total release cycle. Then there are development, alpha and beta releases. Therefore that answer also depends on which feature for which component is to be released/updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no commitment from Google on this. And, from my experience, it's mostly related to the development team. Some are very ahead of time to release TF module, and even, sometimes, better module in TF than in Deployment Manager. Other teams are slower.

Terraform is a very popular tool and the team do their best to quickly release module on it, but the delay is not predictible.